# How do I download .MBTiles (Project / Data) from my Mapbox account?

Tags: export, mapbox, tilemill, mbtiles

I need a .MBTiles file to store an android tablet.

How do I download .MBTiles (Project / Data) from my Mapbox account?

See:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRisc.gif

Comment: so where does programming come into play with you question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download tilesets using the tileset web service:

```
http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{account}/tilesets.json
```

You'll see a JSON list of data where you can download the MBTiles.

Answer (score 1):

From the URL that @geografa shared, you can figure out the pattern to download any tileset if you've got the account name and the tileset id.

```
https://api.mapbox.com/v3/{account}.{tileset_id}.mbtiles
```

This works for all of my own tilesets that I tested.

Comment: I get {"message":"Unauthorized"} although I am logged onto mapbox studio.

Comment: Also tried to apend "?access_token=..." but didn't help.